# How to run img slider without stopping?

Tags: javascript

I want to make a img slider but it stops after it reaches the end. Why does it stop once it goes around?

When I run this code, the sequence is **1-2-3-4-5-6-1**:

```js
if ((n+1) > size) {
   n = 0;
}
```

As you see that, I changed the high number to zero. Then the **n** become **0**. So I thought the **n** start to increase until **5**  again.

**My code:**

```js
var n = 0;
var sec = 1000;

setInterval(function() {
  n++;
  showSlides(n);

}, sec);

function showSlides(n) {
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
  var size = slides.length;

  if ((n + 1) > size) {
    n = 0;
  }

  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
    slides[i].style.display = "none";
  }

  slides[n].style.display = "block";

}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title></title>
  <script defer src="main.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="slideshow-container">
    <div class="mySlides fade">
      <div class="numbertext">1 / 6</div>
      <img src="https://divisare-res.cloudinary.com/images/f_auto,q_auto,w_800/v1491425456/ltekybkstiyl7faumrsq/acne-studios-acne-studio-potsdamer-strasse.jpg" style="width:100%">
      <div class="text">ACNE STUDIO</div>
    </div>
    <div class="mySlides fade">
      <div class="numbertext">2 / 6</div>
      <img src="https://divisare-res.cloudinary.com/images/f_auto,q_auto,w_800/v1491425435/hwxwxqxfwo4htfgqksbu/acne-studios-acne-studio-potsdamer-strasse.jpg" style="width:100%">
      <div class="text">ACNE STUDIO</div>
    </div>
    <div class="mySlides fade">
      <div class="numbertext">3 / 6</div>
      <img src="https://divisare-res.cloudinary.com/images/f_auto,q_auto,w_800/v1491425448/rnelglmoujifzlbzykxw/acne-studios-acne-studio-potsdamer-strasse.jpg" style="width:100%">
      <div class="text">ACNE STUDIO</div>
    </div>
    <div class="mySlides fade">
      <div class="numbertext">4 / 6</div>
      <img src="https://divisare-res.cloudinary.com/images/f_auto,q_auto,w_800/v1491425434/coct9kmra7uhmeu4cxto/acne-studios-acne-studio-potsdamer-strasse.jpg" style="width:100%">
      <div class="text">ACNE STUDIO</div>
    </div>
    <div class="mySlides fade">
      <div class="numbertext">5 / 6</div>
      <img src="https://divisare-res.cloudinary.com/images/f_auto,q_auto,w_800/v1491425440/xacfj7abitmifeyciiia/acne-studios-acne-studio-potsdamer-strasse.jpg" style="width:100%">
      <div class="text">ACNE STUDIO</div>
    </div>
    <div class="mySlides fade">
      <div class="numbertext">6 / 6</div>
      <img src="https://divisare-res.cloudinary.com/images/f_auto,q_auto,w_800/v1491425434/cqxjhpdmepxto0nudsok/acne-studios-acne-studio-potsdamer-strasse.jpg" style="width:100%">
      <div class="text">ACNE STUDIO</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's see what's happening here :-

You have a global variable `n` which you also pass as a parameter to `showSlides` which makes a local copy of it inside `showSlides` so updating it won't actually change the global `n`.

Either you don't pass `n` at all to `showSlides` so that what you update inside the function ends up to be global `n` or you perform the check to reset `n` inside the `setInterval` before passing it to `showSlides`.

Answer (score 0):

since n is passed in to showSlides function as parameter, you have to check the n value before passing it in.

```js
var n = 0; 

  var sec = 1000;
  setInterval(function() {
    var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
    var size = slides.length;
    n = n + 1 === size ? 0 : n +1;
    showSlides(n);
  }, sec);


function showSlides(n) {
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
  var size = slides.length;

  for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
      slides[i].style.display = "none";
  }

  slides[n].style.display = "block";
  
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
    <script defer src="main.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
      
    <div class="slideshow-container">

    
      <div class="mySlides fade">
        <div class="numbertext">1 / 6</div>
        <img src="https://divisare-res.cloudinary.com/images/f_auto,q_auto,w_800/v1491425456/ltekybkstiyl7faumrsq/acne-studios-acne-studio-potsdamer-strasse.jpg" style="width:100%">
        <div class="text">ACNE STUDIO</div>
      </div>

      <div class="mySlides fade">
        <div class="numbertext">2 / 6</div>
        <img src="https://divisare-res.cloudinary.com/images/f_auto,q_auto,w_800/v1491425435/hwxwxqxfwo4htfgqksbu/acne-studios-acne-studio-potsdamer-strasse.jpg" style="width:100%">
        <div class="text">ACNE STUDIO</div>
      </div>

      <div class="mySlides fade">
        <div class="numbertext">3 / 6</div>
        <img src="https://divisare-res.cloudinary.com/images/f_auto,q_auto,w_800/v1491425448/rnelglmoujifzlbzykxw/acne-studios-acne-studio-potsdamer-strasse.jpg" style="width:100%">
        <div class="text">ACNE STUDIO</div>
      </div>

      <div class="mySlides fade">
        <div class="numbertext">4 / 6</div>
        <img src="https://divisare-res.cloudinary.com/images/f_auto,q_auto,w_800/v1491425434/coct9kmra7uhmeu4cxto/acne-studios-acne-studio-potsdamer-strasse.jpg" style="width:100%">
        <div class="text">ACNE STUDIO</div>
      </div>

      <div class="mySlides fade">
        <div class="numbertext">5 / 6</div>
        <img src="https://divisare-res.cloudinary.com/images/f_auto,q_auto,w_800/v1491425440/xacfj7abitmifeyciiia/acne-studios-acne-studio-potsdamer-strasse.jpg" style="width:100%">
        <div class="text">ACNE STUDIO</div>
      </div>

      <div class="mySlides fade">
        <div class="numbertext">6 / 6</div>
        <img src="https://divisare-res.cloudinary.com/images/f_auto,q_auto,w_800/v1491425434/cqxjhpdmepxto0nudsok/acne-studios-acne-studio-potsdamer-strasse.jpg" style="width:100%">
        <div class="text">ACNE STUDIO</div>
      </div>

   
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Or just don't pass n